# Need to be able to update a Custom Data but nothing else

Tags: custom-fields, permissions, acl

Before posting I search a lot and try few combinations without success...

What I would like to put in place is the following scenario : create 2 user groups, one that is able to create new contact and edit all fields (let's say AUTHOR), one that is able to view all contacts and can update only one custom data but nothing else (let's say COMMENTATOR).

Here is how I tried to manage that:

- In Drupal role management, I have deactivated *CiviCRM: access all custom data* option for COMMENTATOR role.
- I have mapped COMMENTATOR Drupal role to COMMENTATOR CiviCRM group thanks to CiviGroup Roles Sync module.
- In CiviCRM Administer/USers and permissions/Permissions (Access Control), I have created COMMENTATOR ACL role and then have made the link with COMMENTATOR group.
- In Manage ACLs, I had a new ACL for Role COMMENTATOR, with operation Edit on a set of custom data fields linked to Custom Data COMMENT (properly created before).

When I log with an account with COMMENTATOR role, I can see my list of contact and can't update anything, even not the COMMENT Custom Data (but I see it)...

My first question is : is it possible to do in CiviCRM what I'm trying to do ?
If so, obviously I missed something... What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance for your help and advices !

P.S : I work with CiviCRM 4.6.10 on Drupal 6 and, unfortunately, I can only have access to the UI (no access to database or PHP files...)

Comment: I have the same question.  Did you get an answer to this question?  I would like to do the opposite.  That is allow editing summary contact data but view only custom data.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider using [webform_civicrm](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_civicrm) module. I don't recall how up to date it is with drupal 6 but it should allow you to give your commentators a form which is restricted to just that role, and which has an autocomplete to find the contact and the desired custom field to enter their comment in.

it might even be better if you use the form to add the 'comment' as an Activity if there is the possibility of many 'commentators' adding comments.

Comment: Thanks for this input. I will have a look, maybe it could fit my needs. But actually, AUTHOR, COMMENTATOR and COMMENT in my question are just examples to illustrate the purpose. But the question at the back is really : is it possible to manage permissions and ACLs to only have the possibility to create/update a Custom data in a Contact and nothing else ?